# Unable to identify and click on the button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I am Running my `Selenium Web driver + TestNG + Java` browser compatibility tests on `Browserstack` from my windows 10 machine.

```
WebDriver driverSafari;
```

Below is my desired capabilities:

```
   DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
   caps.setCapability("browser", "Safari");
   caps.setCapability("browser_version", "11.0");
   caps.setCapability("os", "OS X");
   caps.setCapability("os_version", "High Sierra");
   caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "false");
   caps.setCapability("browserstack.selenium_version", "3.5.2");
   caps.setCapability("resolution", "1024x768");
   driverSafari = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
   driverSafari.get("https://testsite.com/");
   WebElement element = driverSafari.findElement(By.name("password"));
    element.sendKeys("somepassword");
    element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driverSafari.manage().window().maximize();
    driverSafari.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    driverSafari.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='findAClass']")).click();
   WebElement element2 = driverSafari.findElement(By.xpath("// [contains(text(),'Filters')]"));
  element2.click();
```

It is throwing error at this line `WebElement element2..`. I could see the test `url` loading in Safari browser in `Browserstack` and but it can't be clicked on the `Filters` button

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {applicationCacheEnabled: true, browserName: safari, cleanSession: true, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: true, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, version: 13605.3.8, webStorageEnabled: true}

*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=span[@title='Filters']}
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Removed the screenshot and formatted, but some users asked how does the `html tags` looks like to so thought of sharing the html screenshot. Thank you for suggesting that.

Comment: You definitely should include the HTML but as plain text instead of a screenshot. Many times I will take the HTML that a asker posts, put it into a sample page, and then create locators and test them. I can't do that with a screenshot and I'm not going to take the time to transcribe the text from a screenshot. Screenshots are fine but they should be limited to UI to give context to the question. Code (including HTML), error messages, etc. should always be posted in plain text and properly formatted.